# Select Query: Elimate repeated duplicate rows without group by

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table like this where Student(id, attempt)
data goes as follows:

| id | attempt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

i want to find the highest attempt for the student ex: student1 got exams cleared in his 3rd attempt

final output must go like

| id | attempt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |

I don't want to use where, group by, because i am creating a view and will be joining multiple tables

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(attempts)as MaxCreated
                FROM SHRTCKG
                GROUP BY id, attempts) u
        ON x.id = u.attempts
        AND x.id = u.attempts)
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT - _except those who are arguments to aggregate functions_!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the maximum attempt per ID and show the results ordered by ID? That is the most basic aggregation:

```
select id, max(attempt)
from shrtckg
group by id
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use window function `MAX()` if it is not possible to use `GROUP BY` :

```
select distinct id, MAX(attempt) over (partition by id) as attempt
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-ZwhBxhR)

Comment: wouldn't it repeat rows i am trying to create a view here

Comment: Using ‘distinct’ will prevent getting duplicates check my update

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query using SQL server. This is basically the maximum value of attempt for each id.

```
select 
       id , 
       max(attempt) as max_attempt from Student as a 
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it without WHERE and GROUP BY (don't know why, though) then the solution could be MODEL clause (with Distinct):

```sql
WITH  --  S a m p l e   D a t a : 
    tbl (ID, ATTEMPT) As
        (   Select 1,   1 From Dual Union All 
            Select 1,   2 From Dual Union All
            Select 1,   3 From Dual Union All
            Select 1,   4 From Dual Union All
            Select 2,   1 From Dual Union All
            Select 2,   2 From Dual 
        )
```

... here is the code:

```sql
-- M a i n   S Q L :
SELECT  Distinct ID, COUNT_ATTEMPT "ATTEMPT"
FROM    (   Select  ID, ATTEMPT, 0 "COUNT_ATTEMPT" From tbl )
MODEL   Dimension By    ( ID, ATTEMPT   )
        Measures        ( COUNT_ATTEMPT )
RULES   (   COUNT_ATTEMPT[ANY, ANY] = Count(COUNT_ATTEMPT)[CV(ID), ATTEMPT > 0] )
```

... ...

```sql
--    R e s u l t :
--          ID    ATTEMPT
--  ---------- ----------
--           1          4
--           2          2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scalar subquery like this:

```
select distinct id, 
(select MAX(attempt) 
  from mytable t2
  where t2.id = t.id) as attempt
from mytable t
```